# Sublime shortcuts for commonly type code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

I use Sublime often and I find myself typing many of the same bits of boilerplate code on a very regular basis.

For example, something as mundane as

```
<div class="row">
</div>
```

Is there any way I can create a shortcut key (i.e. something like `CTRL`+`r`) to speed this up each time?

Answer (score 1):

This simple task can be achieved without any additional plugins ("vanilla" Sublime Text) and using Emmet plugin.

## Vanilla Sublime Text

You can create snippets for repeating code templates. Click *Tools* → *New snippet...*, a new file will be opened:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

You can enter your code template in the CDATA block:

```
(...)
    <content><![CDATA[
<div class="row">
    ${1:<!-- code goes here -->}
</div>
]]></content>
(...)
```

Then uncomment the `<scope>` tag (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>) and put `text.html` inside it:

```
<scope>text.html</scope>
```

Now uncomment `<tabTrigger>` and put your shorthand phrase in it, for example:

```
<tabTrigger>row</tabTrigger>
```

Finally, save the file. Sublime Text will open the *Save* window in its `User` directory. Save the snippet there or create your own subfolder. Filename will become snippet's name. Extension must be `.sublime-snippet`. In my case the full path will be:

```
C:\Users\gronostaj\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Bootstrap row.sublime-snippet
```

And here's complete snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<div class="row">
    ${1:<!-- code goes here -->}
</div>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>row</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

To use it, simply open any HTML document, make sure highlighting is set to HTML, type `row` (the shorthand from `<tabTrigger>` tag) and press either <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Sublime Text will expand the snippet:

[image: Expanded snippet Image]

Note that contents of the tag are automatically highlighted because I set up a template variable. You can add more of them (like `${2:...}`, `${3:...}`) and navigate between them with <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Re-using variable numbers will bind variable contents together (ie. changing it in one place will affect it everywhere).

## Emmet

Emmet is every developer's must-have tool. First you have to install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation). Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Sublime Text, type `install` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Package Controll will download list of available plugins. Type `emmet` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to install it. Progress will be shown in statusbar. Then restart Sublime Text.

Emmet will enable building HTML with CSS selectors. For example you can type `.row` in any HTML document and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see this:

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

There's much more you can do with Emmet - try this:

```
aside.sidebar>.links>ul>li>a.sidebarLink[target=_blank]
```

Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and watch Emmet's magic happening in front of your eyes:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="sidebarLink" target="_blank"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```